# Card Flip animation in HTML CSS not working in IE

Tags: html, css

This card clip HTML component uses just HTML and CSS, it works except on IE11. On IE11, it is slow and laggy. When I remove backface-visibility:hidden, then it works perfectly on IE11 but I obviously need that line.

What potential fixes are there

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKWPVb

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__side card__side--front">

  </div>

  <div class="card__side card__side--back ">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .card {
  width: 200px;
  perspective: 150rem;
  -moz-perspective: 150rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 52rem;

}
.card__side {
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #808080;
  height: 50rem;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 800ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.card__side--front {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;

}
.card__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card:hover .card__side--front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card:hover .card__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

html {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a “Backface-visibility:hidden” alternative for IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635279/is-there-a-backface-visibilityhidden-alternative-for-ie11)

Comment: I tested on IE v11.0.9600.19035 and I'm not getting any choppiness or issues.

Answer (score 1):

Issue in IE is caused with transition.
If using 2 div elements is not necessary to you, I would suggest something like that:

```
   <div class="card">

  <div class="card__side card__side--back ">

  </div>
</div>



   .card {
  width: 200px;
  perspective: 150rem;
  -moz-perspective: 150rem;
  position: relative;
  height: 52rem;

}
.card__side {
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #808080;
  height: 50rem;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 800ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  //backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__side--back {

  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card:hover .card__side--back {
  transform:  rotateY(0deg);
   background: red;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

html {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

Comment: that defeats the purpose of the whole interactive. its suppose to slip to another side

Comment: The view is the same. Div flips and changes color. If you need two divs for another purpose ,so my suggestion will not fit your needs..

Comment: I need two divs because one side should have text content and the other as well